# PDF plugin issue with Sonar 5.1

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to use **SonarQube version 5.1.** But there is no PDF Plugin support for this version of SonarQube as per my limited knowledge, hence I am **not able to Generate/Download PDF format** for analysis I have done.

Can anyone suggest as what configuration can be done using below versions to generate and download PDF.

I am using below version :

`SonarQube 5.1 – Apr. 2, 2015
MYSQL Server version: 5.5.29`

Embedded  mysql jar  inside SonarQube: /lib/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [Plugin Version Matrix page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix):

- the [community PDF Report plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin) is indeed not compatible with 5.1
- but [SonarSource Report plugin](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/report.html) (that also generates PDF reports) is compatible.

Comment: Thank You for quick help ! I can see the 'Report'  on LHS of Sonar GUI. Can you please suggest as how to download the project report in PDF from here. I have analysed one project and can see the same on  Sonarqube GUI page.